# Imprimir Itens Página Web

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Gostaria de saber como faço para imprimir uma página web, só que eu não gostaria de imprimir toda a página, gostaria que imprimisse o título, e alguns grids, que estão formatados (seria necessário imprimir todos os dados do GridView, sem paginação).

Infelizmente de todas as formas que eu tento, não imprimi o grid sem formatação. A paginação é feita no controle do GridView mesmo.

Alguém sabe alguma forma, que consigo imprimir o grid com todos os dados?

Comment: É ASP.NET ou WinForms?

Comment: é Asp.net webForms, a tag foi errada, já vou alterar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, fazendo a configuração desta forma:

```html
sb.Append("<div ID='imprimir' align='Center' style='font-size:25px;'>Relatório de Planos</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei sobre ASP, então talvez o que eu vá te dizer aqui não funcione muito bem.

No CSS temos as media queries, que basicamente são "modos" em que sua página se encontra. Exemplo:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
   body{
        width: 100%
   }
}
```

Ou seja, quando o dispositivo for screen (tela) e tiver no máximo 600px de largura, aplica largura de 100% no body.

Com isso também temos algumas opções que tratam sobre impressão (`print`). Então você pode usa-las da seguinte maneira:

```
@media print{
    #my-grid{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 600px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Ou seja, quando o você tentar imprimir pelo navegador, o elemento `#my-grid` vai receber esses novos valores e substituir os antigos.

Uma forma de testar se o seu estilo está sendo aplicado corretamente é utilizando o DevTool.

No chrome, abra o console (f12), aperte ESC e role até a opção `Emulate CSS Media`. Lá você pode selecionar `print` (impressão) e verificar como teu elemento fica quando vai ser impresso.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia Raul, tentei fazer como informou com o título para que aparecesse configurado, fiz dessa forma: @media print {
    #lblTitulo {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 200;
        color: #33cc00;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 130px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        width: 100%;
    }
} 
Porém não funcionou, tem ideia do porque não está funcionando ? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver fazendo desta forma:

```html
GridSuprimento.DataSource = gridCarregaSuprimento();
            GridSuprimento.AllowPaging = false;
            GridSuprimento.DataBind();
            GridRetirada.DataSource = gridCarregaRetirada();
            GridRetirada.AllowPaging = false;
            GridRetirada.DataBind();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            GridSuprimento.RenderControl(hw);
            GridRetirada.RenderControl(hw);
            string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
            sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
            sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
            sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
            sb.Append(lblTitulo.Text);
            sb.Append(gridHTML);
            sb.Append("\");");
            sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
            sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
            sb.Append("printWin.print();");
            sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());
```

Aparece os Grid Carregados e os títulos, porém sem configuração, preciso saber como configuro os títulos, ainda não consegui resolver esta parte.